# Galois group of the splitting field of a cyclotomic polynomial

Tags: galois-theory

Let $f(x) = x^4 + 1$,that is  $f(x) = \Phi_8 (x)$. So one of the four primitive 8'th roots of unity is $w = e^{\pi i/4}$, giving that $E = \mathbb{Q}(w)$ is the splitting field of $\Phi_8(x)$. By a theorem in my book I then also know that $[E:\mathbb{Q}] = |Gal(E/\mathbb{Q})| = \phi(8) =4$, and also that $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_{8}^*$, the multiplicative group formed by units of $\mathbb{Z}_8$. So then $Gal(E/\mathbb{Q}) = \{1,3,5,7\}$.

The exercise asked me to describe the Galois group, and when asked to do that I never know what description is sufficient. Is this a sufficient description of it, or is there more? And more important, have I made mistakes?

Comment: There are two groups of order four, a cyclic one and the Klein four-group, which one is it?

Comment: As a teacher I would be happy if you added: 1) why does adjoining that one root suffice (probably covered by a theorem in your book), and 2) what the automorphisms do to $w$, and why does known $\sigma(w)$ identify $\sigma$ fully. If you have covered Galois correspondence, a natural follow-up question is to identiy the intermediate fields.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you for the detailed comment.